# ART cause my app ANR?

Tags: android

Log:

> java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown
>     at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
>     at java.lang.ProcessManager.(ProcessManager.java:62)
>     at java.lang.ProcessManager.(ProcessManager.java:335)
>     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
>     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:128)

Why this could happen?

Sure,it's from my app's process.

There will be a variety of circumstances led to the emergence of this error.

Full stack trace:

`1.first time:
MainCoreService#MainCoreAsyncTask#Error > java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown
    at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.<init>(ProcessManager.java:62)
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.<clinit>(ProcessManager.java:335)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:128)
    at sb.a(Unknown Source)
    at su.e(Unknown Source)
    at su.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.mymoney.sms.service.MainCoreService.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.mymoney.sms.service.MainCoreService.a(Unknown Source)
    at afk.a(Unknown Source)
    at afk.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
    at ym.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`

`2.Second time:
MainCoreService#MainCoreAsyncTask#Error > java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown
    at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.enableConnectionGC(AbstractConnPool.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.createConnectionPool(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.<init>(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:98)
    at os.a(Unknown Source)
    at os.a(Unknown Source)
    at kt.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.mymoney.sms.service.MainCoreService.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.mymoney.sms.service.MainCoreService.a(Unknown Source)
    at afk.a(Unknown Source)
    at afk.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
    at ym.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`

All have reported that is the same mistake:`java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown`

Comment: First: post a complete stack trace. Second: Is there some reason you think ART is causing this?

Comment: Third: are you sure that message is coming from your app's process?

Comment: Sure,it's from my app's process.